Identify if all bools in a list are the same value, and what the distinct value is if they are the same
Is there a cleaner way to identify if the bools in a List<bool> are all true, all false, or mixed?
I've done it by having a nullable bool? and then doing the following:
bool? result;
    
if (ls.TrueForAll(x => x == true))
{
    result = true;
}
else if (ls.TrueForAll(x => x == false))
{
    result = false;
}
else
{
    result = null;
}

However this requires iterating the list twice and feels like a slightly long-winded way to do this, and also feels like a problem that has probably already been solved.
I'm not too worried about performance as in my code it's not happening a lot or very often, so I'm more interested in a cleaner way to achieve this.
Here's a dotnetfiddle with setup/demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UuPYW0

Pop the first (if possible!) and the remaining list must all be the first element.

What do you want to return when all the values are true and all the values are false - i.e. for the empty list?

The list is not actually iterated twice, since the TrueForAll method's "processing is stopped when the delegate returns false for any element". So in one of the branches, processing stops after the first element.

Boring..

All you need to do is:

Get the first boolean array component \$b_1\$,
Iterate the rest of the array components \$b_2, \ldots, b_n\$,
If some array component from (2) does not match \$b_1\$, return null,
Otherwise, return \$b_1\$

I had this hypothetical code in mind:
static bool? GetListBool(bool[] boolArray)
{
    bool selector = boolArray[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < boolArray.Length; i++) 
    {
        if (boolArray[i] != selector) 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return selector;
}


Yep that does it. Should have thought of that!

What happens when you pass an empty array?

@Bergi Array index out of bounds exception, I know. Two options: (1) return null, or don’t catch and rethrow.

const bool selector = boolArray[0]; gives a "Constant initializer must be compile-time constant" error. Remove the const.

@PiersMyers I mentioned in my answer that my code is hypothetical. I don’t really do C#.

You can still [edit] your answer to be valid C# when people who do know the language point out improvements that are easy to make.  Or I can do that for you since you didn't bother initially.

It could be this simple (as it was suggested by Joop Eggen):
return list.All(x => x == list[0]) ? list[0] : null;


UPDATE #1
The above code does not handle the case when the collection is empty. Because the question does not mention any specify requirements for that case it is up to the OP to decide how to handle it.
To treat it as null
return list.Any() && list.All(x => x == list[0]) ? list[0] : null;

To treat it as false
return list.Any() 
    ? list.All(x => x == list[0]) ? list[0] : null
    : false;

To treat it as true
return list.Any() 
    ? list.All(x => x == list[0]) ? list[0] : null
    : true;

To throw a custom exception
return list.Any() 
    ? list.All(x => x == list[0]) ? list[0] : null
    : throw new CustomException();

It is worth noting that the .All() method short circuits, so the performance is similar to @coderodde's answer for fewer loc. It would be preferable to use LINQ rather than DIY'ing your own.

Fine, handles the empty list as in the original question.

@JoopEggen Nope, it does not handle. It will fail with ArgumentOutOfRangeException. But if you add list.Any() && before list.All then problem solved :D

Ahh, I am not familiar with C#, thought that All would be a noop whenever the list is empty. But it seems to yield true then. Okay.

@JoopEggen Yepp All is safe. list[0] is not.

This is also a good solution, thanks.

Since no one else has mentioned it, I assume it's (list.Any() && list.All(x => x == list[0])) ? list[0] : null, not list.Any() && (list.All(x => x == list[0]) ? list[0] : null)? Come to think of it, what really is the desired result for an empty list?

@JollyJoker Since the question does not specify any requirements how to deal with empty collections I think it's up to the OP to decide how to implement that part.

@PeterCsala I guess that means the original version without list.Any() would have been better

@JollyJoker I've updated the post accordingly.

The statement "all booleans in this list are true" is vacuously true for the empty list. The statement "all booleans in this list are false" is also vacuously true for the empty list. Therefore, according to the OP's specification, the correct return value for the empty list is the quantum superposition of both true and false :-D

@JörgWMittag nice

@JörgWMittag You'll need Raku's Junction type for that: https://glot.io/snippets/h1828weii3
